# Seed a pivot table using factories in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, factory, laravel-seeding

I'm new to Laravel and I'm looking for a good way to seed a pivot table using **factories**. I don't want to use plain seeders. I'll show you the case:

I have three tables (**users**, **skills**, and **user_skill**).

```
users                user_skill                 skills
+----------------+   +----------------------+   +-----------------+
| id  | name     |   | user_id | section_id |   | id  | skills    |
+----------------+   +----------------------+   +-----------------+
| 1   | Alex     |   |         |            |   | 1   | draw      |
|----------------|   |----------------------|   |-----------------|
| 2   | Lucy     |   |         |            |   | 2   | program   |
|----------------|   |----------------------|   |-----------------|
| 3   | Max      |   |         |            |   | 3   | social    |
|----------------|   |----------------------|   +-----------------+
| 4   | Sam      |   |         |            |
+----------------+   +----------------------+
```

Is there a good way to take real `Id`'s of the Users table and real `Id`'s of Skills table to seed the pivot table? I want to do it randomly, but I don't want random numbers that doesn't match to any id. I want the Id to match with the **users** and **skills**.

I don't know how to start, and I'm looking for a good example. Maybe something like this?

```
$factory->defineAs(App\User::class, 'userSkills', function ($faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => ..?
        'skills_id' => ..?
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I do not think that this is the best approach but it works for me.

```
$factory->define(App\UserSkill::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'user_id' => factory(App\User::class)->create()->id,
        'skill_id' => factory(App\Skill::class)->create()->id,
    ];
});
```

If you do not want to create a model just for the pivot table, you can insert it manually.

```
DB::table('user_skill')->insert(
    [
        'user_id' => factory(App\User::class)->create()->id,
        'skill_id' => factory(App\Skill::class)->create()->id,
    ]
);
```

Or, with random existing values.

```
DB::table('user_skill')->insert(
    [
        'user_id' => User::select('id')->orderByRaw("RAND()")->first()->id,
        'skill_id' => Skill::select('id')->orderByRaw("RAND()")->first()->id,
    ]
);
```

Comment: But this way you need to create a Model `UserSkill` for the pivot table `user_skill`? And this is not necessary right?
There is no way to seed that sable just taking the current `id`'s of the `users` and `skills` tables?

Answer (score 17):

For those who are using laravel 8.x and are looking for a solution to a problem like this;

In laravel 8.x you can feed your pivot using Magic Methods,
For example if you have a belongsToMany relation named "userSkills" in User model, you should feed the pivot table this way:

`User::factory()->hasUserSkills(1, ['skills' => 'draw'])->create();`

[You can find the documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#many-to-many-relationships-using-magic-methods)

Comment: Any ideas how to do this for a polymorphic relationship? Eg. commentable()

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem and I resolved this way on Laravel testing.

Don't need to create a new UserSkills Model:

Version Laravel 5.7

## Database

```
users                user_skill                               skills
+----------------+   +------------------------------------+   +-----------------+
| id  | name     |   | user_id | section_id | state_skill |   | id  | skills    |
+----------------+   +------------------------------------+   +-----------------+
| 1   | Alex     |   |         |            |             |   | 1   | draw      |
|----------------|   |----------------------|-------------|   |-----------------|
| 2   | Lucy     |   |         |            |             |   | 2   | program   |
|----------------|   |----------------------|-------------|   |-----------------|
| 3   | Max      |   |         |            |             |   | 3   | social    |
|----------------|   |----------------------|-------------|   +-----------------+
| 4   | Sam      |   |         |            |             |
+----------------+   +----------------------+-------------+
```

## User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;
    
    public function skills()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Skill')
                ->withTimestamps()
                ->withPivot('state_skill');
    }
}
```

## DataBaseTest.php

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class DataBaseTest extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * @test
     */    
    public function test_create_user_skill()
    {
       // Create DataBase
       $users = factory(\App\User::class, 1)
           ->create()
           ->each(function ($user) {

                // Create Models Support
                $skill = factory(\App\Skill::class)->create();
                
                // Create Pivot with Parameters
                $user->skills()->attach($skill->id,[
                    'state_skill' => 'ok'
                ]);
 
            });

        // Testing
        // ...
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Seed Models and pivot table using factories:

Tested using Laravel 10.6 with PHP 8.1 , assuming you have your factories all set for User & Role Models.

### 1. Many to Many :

```
$roles= Role::factory(3)->create(); 
$users= User::factory(3)->hasAttached($roles)->create();
```

#### It creates:

- 3 Roles
- 3 Users with every user attached to the 3 roles created
- 9 role_user record

NB: use loop to get as much as u want

### 2. One to One placeholder one-liner :

```
User::factory(20)->has(Role::factory())->create();
```

#### It creates:

- 20 Users
- 20 Roles
- 20 role_user records (one-to-one  user_id = role_id)